# Python - write() adding content I didn't expect

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am playing with the file I/O functions, and I am having issues writing to a file.

To get a feel for it, I have either run a FOR loop on a range, adding each to a new line, or done the same for a list.  Either way, I get the following appended to the file after the loop:

```
98
99
is dropped.

"""

        global quitting

        try:

            raise

        except SystemExit:

            raise

        except EOFError:

            global exit_now

            exit_now = True

            thread.interrupt_main()

        except:

            erf = sys.__stderr__

            print>>erf, '\n' + '-'*40

            print>>erf, 'Unhandled server exception!'

            print>>erf, 'Thread: %s' % threading.currentThread().getName()

            print>>erf, 'Client Address: ', client_address

            print>>erf, 'Request: ', repr(request)

            traceback.print_exc(file=erf)

            print>>erf, '\n*** Unrecoverable, server exiting!'

            print>>erf, '-'*40

            quitting = True

            thread.interrupt_main()



class MyHandler(rpc.RPCHandler):



    def handle(self):

        """Override base method"""

        executive = Executive(self)

        self.register("exec", executive)

        self.console = self.get_remote_proxy("console")

        sys.stdin = PyShell.PseudoInputFile(self.console, "stdin",

                IOBinding.encoding)

        sys.stdout = PyShell.PseudoOutputFile(self.console, "stdout",

                IOBinding.encoding)

        sys.stderr = PyShell.PseudoOutputFile(self.console, "stderr",

                IOBinding.encoding)



        # Keep a reference to stdin so that it won't try to exit IDLE if

        # sys.stdin gets changed from within IDLE's shell. See issue17838.

        self._keep_stdin = sys.stdin



        self.interp = self.get_remote_proxy("interp")

        rpc.RPCHandler.getresponse(self, myseq=None, wait=0.05)



    def exithook(self):

        "override SocketIO method - wait for MainThread to shut us down"

        time.sleep(10)
        <ad nauseum>
```

The code for creating this is:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w+')
for x in range(100):
    f.write((str(x) + '\n'))
f.read()
```

But even if I close it and open the file itself, this stuff is appended.

How can I just write the data to the file without this extra stuff?

Comment: Why are you using `'w+'` as the file mode for just writing? Have you tried *truncating* the file first, I suspect you are just *partially* overwriting an existing file.

Comment: As a style note you should always use pythons with syntax when opening files, for example `with open('test.txt'. 'w+') as f:` This ensures that the file is closed when you are done with it.

Comment: I want to open it for read and write.  Google searches (and possible SO questions) said to use w+.  I believe this was so I could create the file and overwrite it if necessary.  I actually delete all content and save it before I try the code again.

Comment: I just tried it using 'with open(blah, 'r+'), and I get the same results.  UPDATE: It looks like it happens when I read the file while still open.  Does this make a difference?

Comment: You're missing the end quote after `\n`. So the entire rest of your script is being written to the file.

Comment: Is that missing quote in the real script, or a copying error?

Comment: BTW, while you can read from a file that you've just written to, you're not going to read anything if you're at the end of the file. You need to either use `seek` to re-position the file cursor, or close & re-open the file. (If you use `with` to open the file it will automatically be closed when you exit the `with` block).

Comment: @Barmar: I suspect that's IDLE code, not the OP's.

Comment: @PM2Ring I suspect you're right, too. Which makes me think he's accessing a variable that refers to an IDLE function.

Comment: Even ignoring @Barmar's observation, the `read` won't return anything because the file pointer is at end-of-file. Is this really the code causing the problem?

Comment: It looks like if I do seek(0) and then read, it outputs correctly.  So the lack of seek() seems to be appending stuff to the file.  Could it also be because  I named it test.txt?  Is that name too close to a Python file?

Comment: The filename shouldn't matter. You really need to post the whole script, there's obviously something going on that you haven't shown.

Comment: Whole script?  the second code block is exactly what I typed in IDLE that resulted in the described output.  Do you mean post the entire contents of the file?